# Rerurn null if subquery hasn't value sql

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

If this query hasn't B values, but has A values, can I have null where there are no values?

```
SELECT A, B
FROM 
(SELECT title as A
 FROM TABLE1 
 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1_TABLE2_ID = TABLE2_ID
 INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE1_TABLE3_ID = TABLE3_ID
 WHERE TABLE_TABLE3_ID = 2008 AND TABLE_TYP LIKE 'A'),

(SELECT title as B
 FROM TABLE1 
 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1_TABLE2_ID = TABLE2_ID
 INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE1_TABLE3_ID = TABLE3_ID
 WHERE TABLE_TABLE3_ID = 2008 AND TABLE_TYP LIKE 'B')
```

For example, this table must be show

```
  A        B
---------------
Computer  null
```

But now it show the values only if Id has Type A and Type B

Comment: Have a look into FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: How many rows are you expecting to get for `A` and `B` subqueries?

Comment: @MT0, it is always a different value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `LEFT CROSS JOIN`, but you can implement it using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.A, b.B
FROM (SELECT title as A
      FROM TABLE JOIN
           TABLE2
           ON TABLE_TABLE2_ID = TABLE2_ID JOIN
           TABLE3
           ON TABLE_TABLE3_ID = TABLE3_ID
      WHERE TABLE_TABLE3_ID = 2008 AND TABLE_TYP LIKE 'A'
     ) a, LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT title as B
      FROM TABLE JOIN
           TABLE2
           ON TABLE_TABLE2_ID = TABLE2_ID JOIN
           TABLE3
           ON TABLE_TABLE3_ID = TABLE3_ID
      WHERE TABLE_TABLE3_ID = 2008 AND TABLE_TYP LIKE 'B'
     ) b
     ON 1 = 1;
```

Comment: @EmmaW. . . . That is simply an expression that always evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what data you have but you can use `PIVOT`, and avoid a self-join, when you are expecting zero-or-one row per `TABLE_TYP`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bc9293/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 ( table1_table2_id, table1_table3_ID ) AS
SELECT 1, 2008 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TABLE2 ( table2_ID, table_typ ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TABLE3 ( table3_ID, title ) AS
SELECT 2008, 'Computer' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT title,
         table_typ
  FROM   TABLE1 
         INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1_TABLE2_ID = TABLE2_ID
         INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE1_TABLE3_ID = TABLE3_ID
  WHERE  TABLE1_TABLE3_ID = 2008
  AND    TABLE_TYP IN ( 'A', 'B' )
)
PIVOT ( MAX( title ) FOR Table_Typ IN ( 'A' AS A, 'B' AS B ) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bc9293/3/0)**:

```
|        A |      B |
|----------|--------|
| Computer | (null) |
```

If your sub-queries are expecting to return multiple rows then you would not be able to use this exact method (but still [may be able to use `PIVOT`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00b35/2), and avoid the self-join, depending on your requirements).

Comment: Thank you very much, but  that's not exactly what I need. Because then I must to read all data from tables and I use this in `sqldatareader`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A, B
FROM 
(SELECT title as A
FROM TABLE 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE_TABLE2_ID = TABLE2_ID
INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE_TABLE3_ID = TABLE3_ID
WHERE TABLE_TABLE3_ID = 2008 AND TABLE_TYP LIKE 'A')AA
left join
(SELECT title as B
FROM TABLE 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE_TABLE2_ID = TABLE2_ID
INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE_TABLE3_ID = TABLE3_ID
WHERE TABLE_TABLE3_ID = 2008 AND TABLE_TYP LIKE 'B')BB
on AA.A=BB.B

Hope this will solve your problem...
```